# Hiding any application in windows

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing an application to hide programmatically an external process window, I've tried several techniques but none of them seem to work properly with **any** application. For example I managed to hide notepad.exe, but when I try to hide a **java based** application nothing happens.

Here some examples of code I used:

```
Process p = new Process();

p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

p.Start();
```

Or this

```
Process p = new Process();

p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

p.Start();
```

I even tried to move the window out of screen in this way

```
Process p = new Process();

p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
p.Start();

var handle = p.MainWindowHandle;
SetWindowPos(handle, 0, -1000, -1000, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

The last one is the one that worked for most case unless for fixed windows (for example sidebars)

Is there any universal way to handle this?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: You can grab a process using `Process.GetProcessesByName()`, rather than using the file path, this may work better in most instances

Comment: Why do you want to hide an arbitrary application instead of minimizing it?

Comment: Why did you re-tag your question with completely irrelevant tags?  Don't spam tags.  You are not writing VBA or C++ code, this isn't relevant to Winforms at all, and the Visual Studio tag should only be used for questions *about* Visual Studio.

Comment: I need to interact with the application buttons because I'm developing an app that works like a cover, remapping all the buttons with a new graphics without touching the source code of the original app

Comment: @Amy I fixed the tags, you're right

Comment: Once again, stop adding irrelevant tags.  Your question has nothing to do with Winforms and I already explained why the VS tag is not relevant.

Comment: @Amy Isn't the OP actually writing his code in a WinForms project?  I would let that slide.

Comment: @LarsTech I did let that slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using AHK library

https://autohotkey.com/

It provides several functions for task scheduling and automation in windows.

Answer (score 3):

Use User32.dll

```
[DllImport("User32")] 
private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int nCmdShow);
```

The above function accept 2 params and the seconds has these values:

```
SW_HIDE             0
SW_SHOWNORMAL       1
SW_NORMAL           1
SW_SHOWMINIMIZED    2
SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED    3
SW_MAXIMIZE         3
SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE   4
SW_SHOW             5
SW_MINIMIZE         6
SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE  7
SW_SHOWNA           8
SW_RESTORE          9
SW_SHOWDEFAULT      10
SW_FORCEMINIMIZE    11
SW_MAX              11
```

so that you could hide notepad in this way:

```
int hWnd;
Process[] processRunning = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process pr in processRunning)
{
    if (pr.ProcessName == "notepad")
    {
        hWnd = pr.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32();
        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use the standard `ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow)` and avoid hard-coded conversions.

Comment: This is working for several application except the java-based ones. I've got a simple Java app and it didn't work

Comment: @SimoneEsposito It's works event with java programs but you see them as java(.exe) or javaw(.exe) as process name, it depends on which one you use to start your program. I test it and it works. Pay also attention to the processname case.

Comment: @Cod3Flu3nc3 I'm sorry I didin't understand. What do I should pay attention to? I compiled a java application as a .jar then converted it in .exe (when I tried to set the .jar path directly, the debugger gave me an error).

Comment: @Bileragger  He's saying that yes, it works (and I agree) and that you have to target "javaw": Also (I think) that the process name could be case sensitive. It's not. But if you target "javaw.exe", it won't work.

Comment: I solved my problem using AHK (AutoHotKey) library, but the code above didn't work for me.

Comment: @Bileragger okay! Happy you've found a solution!